# PHP pg_connect() does not return in PHP-FPM after MacOS Sonoma Upgrade

Tags: php, postgresql, macos, fpm

I have wasted a lot of time on this and I'm stumped. Anyone have some insight or work arounds? Thanks in advance for your attention...

My PHP/PostgreSQL/NGINX app has been running on MacOS using PHP-FPM installed via Homebrew for years. After upgrading MacOS to Sonoma 14.1 from 13.x, it no longer returns from pg_connect(). I've replicated this on 2 machines as well.

No PHP, NGINX, or PostgreSQL configurations have changed. Only the MacOS upgrade. PostgreSQL connects properly using psql and different --host parameters to access by the same interface.

I created a test script with just the pg_connect(), trying multiple permutations and discovered:

```
<?php
# The following line does not return and the request stops
$db = pg_connect("host=dbserver port=5432 dbname=appdb user=appuser");
echo "success!"
?>
```

- Both pg_connect and pg_pconnect die or don't return from NGINX/PHP-FPM when invoking the test script  (NGINX returns "Bad Gateway).
- Both work when invoking the test script from command line (php -f test.php)
- Removing the "host=xxx" parameter from the connection string works for both cases, and it is able to connect to the local postgresql (not what I need though).
- Variations "host=ip", "host=127.0.0.1", "host=dnsname", "host=localhost" all die or don't return. (FPM)
- I can't find any useful errors in Postgres, NGINX or PHP logs, but in php-fpm.log, I received thousands of these messages:

  WARNING: [pool www] child 82817 exited on signal 9 (SIGKILL) after 0.000208 seconds from start

Could MacOS now be preventing the connection until set to allow?

Versions: MacOS 14.1.1, PHP 8.2.13 also 8.3.0, PostgreSQL 15.5 server, also 16.1. libpq 16.1, nginx/1.25.3, Homebrew 4.1.21; Apple Mac M1

Comment: My guess is that Apple has conveniently installed a firewall that is blocking access to this port.

Comment: any news about this issue? faced the same with PDO

Comment: i've just tried php 8.1 – the same result. looks like the problem not in php version

Comment: similar problems, but with brew's postgres and openssl: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/155651

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I've found the solution here: https://github.com/laravel/valet/issues/1433#issuecomment-1741308660

Add following lines to `/opt/homebrew/etc/php/8.3/php-fpm.d/www.conf`:

```
env['PGGSSENCMODE'] = disable
env['LC_ALL'] = C
```

Then restart PHP. And it starts working!

Comment:  Thank you for finding this! It did work for me as well. Searching revealed: "PGGSSENCMODE behaves the same as the gssencmode connection parameter. This option determines whether or with what priority a secure GSS TCP/IP connection will be negotiated with the server." disable: "only try a non-GSSAPI-encrypted connection." Apparently this is related to SSL connections to PG. *** I did not need the LC_ALL=C which controls the locale, which may be needed depending on the OS and PG DB encoding? I'll enable if I do find an issue with PG data.

Comment: This helps me a lot from stressed cause my native php can connect to the postgres, meanwhile my php-fpm can't. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem, only using PDO instead of pg_connect.

Thank for for posting the note about removing `host:localhost` from the pg_connect statement. Once I removed that from my PDO statement:

Doesn't Work:

```
$dbh = new PDO("pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=test", $user, $pass);
```

Works:

```
$dbh = new PDO("pgsql:dbname=test", $user, $pass);
```

the Postgres connection was working again. Really odd. Here's my stack, should it be useful to anyone else:

MacOS Sonoma 14.1.2 (23B92), Postgresql@16 (Homebrew), PHP@8.3 (Homebrew), libpq 16.1 (Homebrew)

Comment: Also to add — I spent ages thinking it was this error with Postgresql:

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/155651

But, it didn't make any difference to me, since SSL is not used locally. Feels related somehow though...

Comment: I had that same SSL issue at the same time as well. Separated them finally. I ended up using PgBouncer (running on localhost without host param) connecting to my PG server on another box as a workaround (and mimicking my production env as well). PDO likely uses pg_connect/pg_pconnect.

Comment: my postgres database lives in docker, so i can connect only to localhost:5432, not to socker, so the solution does not work for me. any ideas?

Comment: i used volume forwarding to bring the socket outside docker container – this didn't help, stil no connection